# Missing bounty award button

Tags: support, bounty

I received a mail titled "Bounty Grace Period Started" 14 hours ago saying:

> Your bounty on the question … How to handle string data characters
>   that are illegal in XML? … ended and will be auto-closed after the
>   24-hour grace period expires.
>
> If you feel one of them deserves your bounty, award it by clicking the
>   bounty icon to the left of the answer.

But on the [question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280783/how-to-handle-string-data-characters-that-are-illegal-in-xml) I see no such button. What happened?

Answer (score 2):

The bounty was closed just now:

> 2018-11-24 14:01:30Z
>   bounty end
>   Community♦
>   Closed, non-winning bounty for question Id = 53280783

That's just a few minutes ago. Did your email arrive delayed perhaps?

Otherwise, the email told you the bounty had ended and that the grace period had started. Don't read the text *after the 24-hour grace period expires* as *you have 24 hours*; you have *less time than that*, the text you shared doesn't say anything about how much of the grace period is left. Email should never be seen as real-time!

Comment: The email header says: Date: Sat, 24 Nov 2018 00:01:57 +0000 (UTC)
Also the gmail GUI says it was sent 14 hours ago. The grace period should be 24 hours (it says so in the email itself).

Comment: The email does not say that you have 24 hours. It says that the grace period is 24 hours, but it was sent *some time into those 24 hours*; it tells you the bounty already ended. You had 14 hours here.